# Extjs Access record from component column editor

Tags: extjs, combobox, store

I am attempting to create a combobox within grid column. There will be one combobox per row, and the store for that combobox will use the current rows record to determine what should be enabled/disabled in the combobox.

How can I access the current rows record within the `editor` attribute of my `componentcolumn`?

```
{
    text: '',
    xtype: 'componentcolumn',
    editor: {
        xtype: 'combobox',
        store: Ext4.create('app.store.ActionStore', {record: ..?}),
        queryMode: 'local',
        forceSelection: true
    }
}
```

I have something similar to the above for my column. I need to find out how to pass in a valid `record` to the store created above.

I am using Ext 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by implementing the `beforeedit` or `validateedit` events of your grid's editing plugin (row or cell).

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing-event-beforeedit